# How to constrain widgets to the end and top with a relativelayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have been building a relativelayout and I'm running into an issue where there are too many items and it runs on. All layouts are structured so as to be below the top image. I'd like to take a widget and place it in the top right corner and start a new column of items. I have been trying but I don't know what to do.

Would it be better to use a constraintlayout in this case? I tried nesting the whole thing with linearlayouts at first and then realized a relativelayout would be better. Any advice on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your purpose? Perhaps add code or wireframes or both?

Comment: The person below was able to figure it out thankfully.  Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understand right you can use

```
  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
  android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

I hope it will work with you .

Comment: Yes! That is exactly what I needed. Thank you very much.